# How to check if userform checkboxes were checked or not; which were dynamically created?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform with dynamic checkboxes(programmed)
Below is my code

```
Dim Rows As Integer
Dim toppart As Integer
Dim Opt As Variant
Dim x As Integer

On Error Resume Next
toppart = 20

UpdateRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("C3:CU3"))

For x = 3 To UpdateRow

Set Opt = Te.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox" & x, True)

Opt.Caption = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, "C").Value

Opt.Width = 70
Opt.Height = 18
Opt.Left = 18

Opt.Top = toppart
toppart = toppart + 20
Next
```

I know if the checkboxes were set via the controls my code will look something like this:

`If (CheckBox1.Value = False) Or (CheckBox2.Value = False) Then
MsgBox "You must select alteast 2 checkboxes", vbCritical`

But when the checkboxes are dynamically created I can't think of a efficient way to do it. Please any suggestions or Help is very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but you can probably loop the controls on your form, check if each is a checkbox, if it is, query it's `.Value` and tally the total number of checkboxes which are "checked. If that number is LTE 1, then you raise your warning/`MsgBox`:

```
Dim checked as Long
Dim ctrl as Object
For Each ctrl in Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
        If ctrl.Value = True Then 
            checked = checked + 1
        End If
    End If
Next
If checked <= 1 Then
    MsgBox "You must select alteast 2 checkboxes", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: `If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then` is the correct syntax

Comment: Thanks @ThomasInzina

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked but, the message box still appears even if i selected at least 2 checkboxes